# Insert multiple cell values to a comment

Tags: excel, vba, comments

I have a task to add a comment in a sumtotal by month to show the items involved and the amount. I Want to simplify the works because Ido it by monthly and every job (over 20 jobs)!

I found solutions for a single cell.

I need to add related cell values to one comment for the month.
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateComment()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim myColumn, myRow As Integer
    
    Set rng = Selection
    myColumn = ActiveCell.Column
    myRow = ActiveCell.Row
    
        
    For Each cel In rng
        If cel.Value <> "" Then
        Range("myColumn" & "1").AddComment [Cell("myRow", "1")).Value & " -$" & Cell("myRow","myColumn")_.value]
        End If
    Next
                
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Add Comments to a Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AddComments()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lCol As Long: lCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("A1").Resize(lRow, lCol)
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    Dim Comm As String
    
    For c = 2 To lCol
        For r = 4 To lRow
            If Len(Data(r, c)) > 0 Then
                n = n + 1
                Comm = Comm & n & ". " & Data(r, 1) & " - " _
                   & Format(Data(r, c), "$#,##0") & vbLf
            End If
        Next r
        If n > 0 Then
            With srg.Cells(1, c)
                .ClearComments
                .AddComment Left(Comm, Len(Comm) - 1)
            End With
            n = 0
            Comm = ""
        End If
    Next c
    
    MsgBox "Comments added.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!!! thats what i need!! But why it dont need to specific a cell to add comment ? Also what mean of if n>0 then....... sorry for the newbie question...

Comment: **1.)** Without the With statement, you can use `srg.Cells(1, c).ClearComments: srg.Cells(1, c).AddComment Left(Comm, Len(Comm) - 1)` which covers the cells from `B1` to `LastCol1` (`For c = 2 to lCol`). **2.)** `If Len(Data(r, c)) > 0 Then` means *that if a value (in the current row of the current column) is found then*. If no value is found for the current column then `n = 0` so no comment will be added even if you have a header in that column: `n` is counting the number of rows (per column) that have an entry.